# ERROR: relation "author" does not exist SQL state: 42P01

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, pgadmin

I am a starter in Postgresql and i am trying to create a simple function with inner join inside it

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetBooks() 
RETURNS TABLE( Id int, Title text, AuthorName text) as
$BODY$   
BEGIN
SELECT bo.Id , bo.Title , au.Name
        FROM "Book" bo INNER JOIN Author au ON (au.Id = bo.AuthorId);

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

when i execute the following

```
SELECT public.getbooks()
```

I am getting this error

```
ERROR:  relation "author" does not exist
LINE 2:       FROM "Book" bo INNER JOIN Author au ON (au.Id = bo.Aut...
                                    ^
QUERY:  SELECT bo.Id , bo.Title , au.Name
        FROM "Book" bo INNER JOIN Author au ON (au.Id = bo.AuthorId)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function getbooks() line 3 at SQL statement
********** Error **********

ERROR: relation "author" does not exist
 SQL state: 42P01
Context: PL/pgSQL function getbooks() line 3 at SQL statement
```

[image: Image where we can see relation exists]

[image: Full Schema]

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: obviously why am i getting this error ?

Comment: because relation "author" does not exist

Comment: why have you double-quoted `"Book"`and not `Author`?

Comment: @VaoTsun Please see picture i've added for relation

Comment: @mcNets i think it doesn't matter because i have tried by removing double quote and by adding on both

Comment: and what happens if you executes the query in the editor?

Comment: you can see the result in picture when i run its giving error

Comment: I mean, the `select` w/o the function.

Comment: you better put screenshot of what is above

Comment: I am getting this `ERROR:  relation "book" does not exist`  if i execute select without function

Comment: @VaoTsun is this ok ?

Comment: Ok can you execute the select statement w/o double-quoted in Book table?  BTW, is it `Book` or `Books`?  Ok, Book I see.

Comment: Yes, it is. @mcNets is right

Comment: `    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetBooks() 
    RETURNS TABLE( Id int, Title text, AuthorName text) as
    $BODY$   
    BEGIN
    SELECT bo."Id" , bo."Title" , au."Name"
            FROM "Book" bo INNER JOIN "Author" au ON (au."Id" = bo."AuthorId");
    
    END;
    $BODY$
      LANGUAGE plpgsql;` does this fix it?..

Comment: @VaoTsun No , now it says `ERROR:  query has no destination for result data`

Comment: try to execute in the editor: `SELECT * FROM Book LEFT JOIN Author ON Author.Id = Book.AuthorId;`

Comment: @mcNets No its giving same result `ERROR: relation "book" does not exist`

Comment: @mcNets gives you a hint, that "Book" != "book", Ahsan

Comment: @VaoTsun ok,  but it's postgresql, it should run http://rextester.com/ZNJZ9001

Comment: you created table with different statement. it was `create table "Author"(`, not `create table Author(`

Comment: http://rextester.com/LTLH77798

Comment: ok, @VaoTsun thanks, I have not noticed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetBooks() 
RETURNS TABLE( Id int, Title text, AuthorName text) as
$BODY$   
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY 
SELECT bo."Id" , bo."Title" , au."Name"
        FROM "Book" bo INNER JOIN "Author" au ON (au."Id" = bo."AuthorId");

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: it works . but giving result like this `(1,"Pride and Prejudice","Jane Austen")` i mean not in columns ... is this normal ? as i am coming from mssql background i didn't know that

Comment: use `SELECT * from public.getbooks()` instead. you created a function that **RETURNS TABLE** - right?